# How to upload multiples files in R without receiving a 421 Too many connections error?

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

I need to upload more than 65 files to my hosting ftp server with `RCurl` but I'm receiving an error after several files have been uploaded :

```
 < 421 Too many connections (8) from this IP
* We got a 421 - timeout!
* Closing connection 291
```

From what I see in the log it says `Connection #283 to host ftp.myserver.com left intact` so that no further authorisation is needed until the connection expire after 15 minutes of inactivity `< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.`.

At least it is my understanding because, for some reason, it resends USER and PASSWORD right after for the second file :

```
> USER admin@myserver.com
< 331 User admin@myserver.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
```

I understand there are multiples authorisation requests (one per file) so that I'm flooding the server.

Is there a possibility to first open a connection to the FTP server then upload all the files ? like in FileZilla ?

Please find the R code I use :

```
for(file in list.files(localPath)) {

  ftpUpload(paste0(localPath,file), userpwd = userpwd, to=paste0("ftp://", ftpPath, file), verbose=TRUE)

}
```

Another SO member has the same problem here but it looks I already use something similar to the response provided to him and it dosen't work. [Using R to upload many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429108/using-r-to-upload-many-files)

Thank you

---

**EDIT** (adding the log) :

```
> for(file in list.files(localPath)) {
+   
+   print(paste0("ftp://", ftpPath, file))
+   ftpUpload(paste0(localPath,file), userpwd = userpwd, to=paste0("ftp://", ftpPath, file), verbose=TRUE)
+ 
+ }
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation-1.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#310)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 2 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||44516|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 44516
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#310)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation-1.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.180 seconds (measured here), 1.15 Kbytes per second
* Connection #310 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation-2.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#311)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 3 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||45077|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 45077
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#311)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation-2.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.207 seconds (measured here), 1.00 Kbytes per second
* Connection #311 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation-3.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#312)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 4 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||40390|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 40390
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#312)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation-3.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.189 seconds (measured here), 1.12 Kbytes per second
* Connection #312 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation-4.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#313)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 5 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||46329|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 46329
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#313)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation-4.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.187 seconds (measured here), 1.11 Kbytes per second
* Connection #313 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation_protected-1.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#314)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 6 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||46556|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 46556
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#314)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation_protected-1.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.186 seconds (measured here), 2.75 Kbytes per second
* Connection #314 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation_protected-2.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#315)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 7 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||43730|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 43730
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#315)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation_protected-2.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.190 seconds (measured here), 2.69 Kbytes per second
* Connection #315 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation_protected-3.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#316)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 8 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||43399|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 43399
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#316)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation_protected-3.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.196 seconds (measured here), 2.61 Kbytes per second
* Connection #316 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_private_allocation_protected-4.csv"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#317)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 9 of 1000 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 08:50. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER cadmin@mywebsite.com
< 331 User cadmin@mywebsite.com OK. Password required
> PASS mypassword
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD portfolios
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /portfolios
> CWD csv
< 250 OK. Current directory is /data/csv
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||48536|)
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connecting to 11.22.33.44 (11.22.33.44) port 48536
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#317)
> TYPE I
< 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
> STOR data_private_allocation_protected-4.csv
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Remembering we are in dir "data/csv/"
[1] "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/data/csv/data_coins_average-1.csv"
< 226-File successfully transferred
< 226 0.184 seconds (measured here), 2.77 Kbytes per second
* Connection #317 to host ftp.mywebsite.com left intact
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 11.22.33.44...
* Connected to ftp.mywebsite.com (11.22.33.44) port 21 (#318)
< 421 Too many connections (8) from this IP
* We got a 421 - timeout!
* Closing connection 318
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Uploading to a URL without a file name!
```

Comment: Have you tried closing any open connections (`?closeAllConnections`)?

Comment: Hi, I just closed a `gzcon` with `closeAllConnections()` but still I have the `421 Too many connections error`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround rather than a solution to my problem but it works like a charm. I created a text file with `ftp` commands inside then launch Ubuntu `ftp` with R `system()`.

ftpcommands.txt :

```
open ftp.mywebsite.com
user admin@mywebsite.com mypassword
lcd ~/R/data/csv
cd data/csv
prompt
mput *.csv
bye
```

Then the `R` command :

```
system("ftp -n < ~/R/data/ftpcommands.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are opening for each file a new connection, which isn't how the *File Transfer Protocol* was meant to be used. Some different solutions:

1. Open less connections in your **R** code.
2. Limit the maximum concurrent connections used by **curl**.
3. Increase the allowed limit of concurrent connections in the config of you **FTP server**. *(Do this only if you really need it, as I mentioned, don't open for each file a connection.)*

Check [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797269/warning-ftp-login-i-cant-accept-more-than-6-connections-as-the-same-user-in/45131091#45131091) out to get a better understanding of the problem. Don't understand me wrong, it's good for the performance to have a little bit more than one connection at the same time, but not for each file, that's definitively too much. The most FTP clients use 2.